# enviar url com parametros na api do whatsapp

Tags: php, whatsapp

Preciso passar uma url com uma variável pela api do whatsapp:

```
$id='3';
$link = "clique neste link para validar sua conta site.com.br/usuario.php?id=$id";

 header("Location: http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&phone=55{$whatsapp}&text={$link}");
```

No caso do código acima, ele não passa a variável $id pelo link e preciso que ele passe.. o link teria que ir para o whatsapss desta forma:

```
"clique neste link para validar sua conta site.com.br/usuario.php?id=3"
```

mas chega no whatsapp assim:

```
 "clique neste link para validar sua conta site.com.br/usuario.php?id"
```

se eu enviar a variável desta forma ela passa:

```
 "clique neste link para validar sua conta site.com.br/$id>" a variável vai para o whatsapp, mas se eu coloco completo não vai.
```

Alguém sabe se tem outro jeito de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Tente concatenar a string usando o `.`.

```
$link = "clique neste link para validar sua conta site.com.br/usuario.php?id=" . $id;
```

Caso o erro persista, execute a função `echo` para verificar se a string está sendo criada corretamente.

`echo $link`

Caso ela esteja sendo criada corretamente, é válido analisar se a API do Whatsapp filtra algumas informações de entrada.

Comment: ele ignora o sinal de igual, não deixa ir para o link, com todos os testes que eu fiz ele parou no id quando tinha um sinal de =. Acho que não tem solução

Comment: quando se trata de aspas duplas a melhor forma de usar na verdader é dessa forma
$link = "clique neste link para validar sua conta site.com.br/usuario.php?id={$id}"; por que as aspas duplas interpreta código php diferente das aspas simples

Answer (score 0):

veja o link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Veja no link acima os códigos dos caracteres:

= é %3D

Espaco é %20

& é %26

entre outros...

Sua linha:

"clique neste link para validar sua conta site.com.br/usuario.php?id=3"

Digitando assim o zap vai colocar o "=" e o "3".

"clique neste link para validar sua conta site.com.br/usuario.php?id%3D3"